# When does a Hamiltonian result in the construction of an IC-POVM?

Tags: entanglement, povm, hamiltonian

Consider a generic $d_A$-dimensional quantum system $A$, for example made of $n$ qubits. Now consider a second higher-dimensional system $B$, with $d_B=d_A^2$, and the quantum map
$$
\rho_A \rightarrow Tr_A[U_{AB} (\rho_A \otimes \eta_B) U_{AB}^{\dagger}],
$$
with $U_{AB}$ unitary operator, followed by a local projective measurement $\{ |k \rangle \langle k |\}$ on $B$, with $k=1,\dots,d_B$.

The resulting POVM acting on the system $A$ is
$$
M_k = Tr_B [ (I\otimes \eta_B) U_{AB}^{\dagger} (I \otimes |k \rangle \langle k| ) U_{AB} ]. 
$$
If $U_{AB} = \exp(-iH_{AB})$, are there any known analytical conditions or theorems that the hamiltonian $H_{AB}$ must satisfy for the POVM $M_k$ to be informationally complete (*i.e.*, it fully spans the space of hermitian operators on $A$)?

The trivial case where $M$ is not informationally complete (IC) is when $U_{AB}$ is a local evolution operator and thus does not entangle $A$ and $B$, in which case $M$ is only composed of the identity operator.

I'm expecting some conditions regarding the expressivity and the entangling capability of the quantum channel ([Ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10876)) and thus on the unitary $U_{AB}$, but I also wanted to find conditions on the generator $H$ which doesn't seem to be trivial.